# How do I place a label at the bottom of a window in Java/SWT

Tags: java, swt

I am writing a Java GUI application using SWT, which shows a large table with hundreds of rows.
At the bottom of the window, I want to have a fixed label showing some status information.

My program looks like this:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();

    Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    FillLayout fillLayout = new FillLayout();
    shell.setLayout(fillLayout);
    // GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    // shell.setLayout(gridLayout);    
    final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.NONE);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    final String header[] = {"Feld 1","Feld 2","Feld 3"};
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
      column.setText(header[i]);
      column.setWidth(100);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
      item.setText(new String[] { "a" + i, "b" + i, "c" + i });
    }
    GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL | GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_FILL);
    gridData.verticalSpan = 3;
    table.setLayoutData(gridData);

    Label statusLine = new Label(shell, SWT.NULL);
    statusLine.setText("This shall be the status line");

    gridData = new GridData(GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_END);
    gridData.horizontalSpan = 3;
    statusLine.setLayoutData(gridData);
            
    shell.setSize(400,100);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
```

}

If I am using a **GridLayout**, the label is located below the table, but depending on the size of the table and the window size, the label is not visible. If I enlarge the window, the label appears, but does not stay at the bottom of the window but always just below the table. And the table is not scrollable, i.e. I cannot see the bottom lines of my large table.

If I am using the **FillLayout**, the table is scrollable, but the label occupies the right half of my window.

Any advise, how I force my label at the bottom of my window and still have table scrollable?

Answer (score 0):

With `GridLayout` you can do something like:

```
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
shell.setLayout(gridLayout);

.... your table code

// To get the table to scroll you have to give a height hint

GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, false, false);
gridData.heightHint = 100;
table.setLayoutData(gridData);

Label statusLine = new Label(shell, SWT.NULL);
statusLine.setText("This shall be the status line");

// Set the label grid data to grab the remaining space and put the label at the bottom

gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.END, true, true);
statusLine.setLayoutData(gridData);

shell.setSize(400, 200);
```

Or have the table grab the excess vertical space:

```
GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, false, true);
gridData.heightHint = 100;
table.setLayoutData(gridData);

Label statusLine = new Label(shell, SWT.NULL);
statusLine.setText("This shall be the status line");

gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.END, true, false);
statusLine.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

Comment: Thank you, your proposal works for me!

Now a related questions pops up:
If I resize my window, the "status line" stays at the bottom as it should be.
But when the window height becomes smaller than the height hint, the status line disappears und when I increase the window size, a blank area appears between my table and the status line.
Is there a way to way to grow and shrink the table area according to the resize of the window?

Comment: I have added an alterative with the table grabbing the excess space. For me that keeps the status line visible. The table should scroll when the space gets small. Resizing the table when there is extra space is a lot more difficult, but you can specify a larger height hint so the table takes up the space most of the time.